# Visual Studio Code colors stopped showing for words in the workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

Very new to coding and VSC still and i had these colors that were really helpful for visualizing,
for example writing:  **word** = input("random word ")  i would have this **word** part in a certain color in the workspace and then another command later in a different color.  Now it shows everything in white text and i can not find the settings to change it back.

Comment: also the "word" used to come as a suggested input for future lines if i just typed "wo..:" and it would suggest to throw the word in it but now it doesn't suggest anything

Comment: color is determined by the Theme, choose a different theme, specify the `another command later` because VSC has a few